# Example VQ-VAE code for audio in paper "Neural Discrete Representation Learning"

Tags: papers, variational-autoencoder, voice-recognition

I want to replicate the paper ["Neural Discrete Representation Learning" by van der Oord et al (2018)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00937). DeepMind provides an example for CIFAR images [on GitHub](https://github.com/google-deepmind/sonnet/blob/v1/sonnet/examples/vqvae_example.ipynb).

It seems that the model for images is quite different from audio. Here is the description of images in the paper:

> We model images by learning a powerful prior (PixelCNN) over z. This allows to not only greatly speed up training and sampling, but also to use the PixelCNNs capacity to capture the global structure instead of the low-level statistics of images.

and here is the description for the experiment with audio:

> We train a VQ-VAE where the encoder has 6 strided convolutions with stride 2 and window-size 4. This yields a latent space 64x smaller than the original waveform. The latents consist of one feature map and the discrete space is 512-dimensional.

I found [this repository](https://github.com/ritheshkumar95/pytorch-vqvae) that seems to implement the VQ-VAE on video. But I couldn't find anything on audio; and [this issue](https://github.com/google-deepmind/sonnet/issues/141), open for 3 years, suggests that the authors won't provide it either.

Does anyone know of an existing example of the VQ-VAE from the paper applied to audio data, such as the VCTK (Voice Cloning Tool Kit)?